# Python not able to request from localhost

Tags: python, python-requests, localhost

I have a julia server running on a localhost which supports POST requests. I'm trying to send a request from python to the julia server but seems python is not able to ping the local host. Results in 403 error

The POST requests work when I try with PostMan and I'm able to see the results as expected (Json file) but not with python. The julia server does not need any auth.

I tired adding proxies, and different User-Agent to `requests.post()` but does not get the results I need. When I add `{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}` I get response 200 but it is scrapping the website (the 404 page, as expected since this is not a website) not requesting the actual server (I'll know when it actually requests the julia server as it prints the results on its server). I requested local jupyter lab url, it's says false but I'm able to open the jupyter lab so my guess is python is not able to send requests from local servers.

Here's sample code:

```
import requests

from urllib import request

def internet_on(): ## this is where I tested to ping jupyter lab, result: False
    try:
        request.urlopen('http://127.0.0.1:7000', timeout=1)
        return True
    except request.URLError as err: 
        return False

internet_on()

proxies = {"http" : "proxy_address"}

data = {"key": "value"}

r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:7000', proxies=proxies, json = data)

>>> r
>>> 403
```

If I use headers:

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/JSON', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:7000', headers=headers, proxies=proxies, json = data)

>>> r
>>> 200 ## but r.contents is the 404 page details not the json file
```

Comment: The word "ping" is misleading here, since nothing here is using "ping".  403 does not mean the site can't be reached.  403 means you DID reach the site, and it rejected the request as "forbidden".  You should not need a proxy to access localhost.

Comment: Yes, Corrected to remove "ping".

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue: https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/879

Added this to code to make it work.

```
NO_PROXY = {
    'no': 'pass',
}

r = requests.post(uri, proxies=NO_PROXY)
```

other method if you want to add universal config:

```
import os

os.environ['NO_PROXY'] = '127.0.0.1'
```

Edit: I figured out the solution right after posting the question here. Not abusing the system. Been stuck on this for 2 days before I posted the question